# MongoDB $project embedded document to root level with other fields in another document

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

i have this structure

```
 {
        "_id": "5e7229c248797243544a15b6",
        "itinerary": [
            {
                "_id": "5e96f905c694d020bc99c2e4"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e7230360bab9640f82a0e79"
            }
        ]
    },
```

and need transform document of this way

```
    { "_id": "5e7229c248797243544a15b6"},
    { "_id": "5e96f905c694d020bc99c2e4"},
    { "_id": "5e7230360bab9640f82a0e79"}
```

thanks for your help team. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            { _id: "$_id" }
          ],
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$itinerary",
              in: "$$this"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_qI-XjvWn6w)

Comment: ¿i can deconstruct the itinerary?

Comment: @DanielLopez what do you need to do?

Comment: I need to leave the itinerary _id at the root level, to later group them.

Comment: @DanielLopez Post please your expeted result, I could change pipeline. If you add `{$undind : "$itinerary"}` before `$project` stage, you can flatten it into separate documents.

Comment: can you see my query

Comment: {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'itineraries',
                        pipeline: [{
                                $match: {
                                    $or: [...]
                                }
                            },
                            { $project: { _id: 0, _id: "$idTour" } },
                        ],
                        as: 'itinerary'
                    },
                }

Comment: this is the lookup for itinerary where i return idTour as _id, inside itinerary.
The _id that accompanies the itinerary is also an idTour, so I want to leave them all at the root and then group them.

Comment: @DanielLopez Check it again, I've updated my answer